# Excel Formating - How do I compare 2 cells and highlight one of them based on the date in 1 Col being further out then the date in the other?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet tracking multiple dates for about 150 people.  I am having a problem however getting dates in Col I to highlight if they are going to be past the date in Col P.

I want Col I Row 4 & 5 to highlight.   How do I write/do this?  Everything I have tried so far has failed.

```
Col I           Col P

06-JAN-2015 15-OCT-2017

01-AUG-2014 10-AUG-2019

17-JUN-2015 25-JUN-2015

10-DEC-2014 05-OCT-2014 - highlight

27-NOV-2014 10-JUL-2014 - highlight

01-JAN-2015 26-AUG-2016
```

Comment: "Everything I have tried so far has failed." – then, show _what_ you tried and didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Conditional Formatting. Follow these steps:

1. Highlight **Col I**.
2. Go to **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule** > **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**.
3. Enter this formula:

   `=$I1>$P1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen first select the column that you want formatted.

Then go to HOME > Conditional Formatting > New Rule

Select the Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Enter the formula such as =$C1>$D1
       $C1 is the first cell is the first column and $D1 is the second column.  If the date in column C is grater than the date in column D then this is true.  Note that the format is $C1 not $C$1.

Now press the Format button and set the formatting you want such as BOLD and color RED.
Press OK
Press OK

If you need to change or edit the rule go to Conditional formatting  Manage Rules.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  While it didn't work completely right, it did help some.  Below is the result I got

02-DEC-2014 22-MAR-2015 - Highlighted Col I
19-OCT-2014 17-NOV-2019
16-JUN-2014 27-MAY-2018
10-MAY-2014 13-AUG-2014
07-JUL-2014 07-SEP-2017 - Highlighted Col I
29-NOV-2014 16-APR-2015
20-MAY-2015 31-JAN-2015 - Highlighted Col I
30-MAR-2015 14-AUG-2017 - Highlighted Col I
15-JUN-2015 06-JUN-2015 - Highlighted Col I

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied sooner.
Please send the formula that you are using and I will see if I can figure out what needs changed....